# 2 Redirects Error in www HTTP to non-www HTTPS 301 Redirection

Tags: wordpress, ssl, redirect, https

I have redirected my WordPress site from http to https using Cloudflare. I installed Let's encrypt SSL via cPanel and did 301 redirection via Cloudflare (not via htaccess). Activated Full SSL (strict) and added Page Rule for "Always Use HTTPS" in Cloudflare.

When checking my site on Redirect Mapper, I am getting error of 2 redirects for "www" version (attached screenshot).

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izGIE.png)

Searched for solutions in Stackoverflow questions/answers and tried different redirection codes given that were to be used in htaccess but none worked.

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: *"tried most of the solutions..."* -  This is basically a different way of  saying a useless "I tried some unspecified thing but it did not work". If you want others to be able to narrow down what you problem might be and what is not your problem based on what you already tried you need say what exactly you have tried and how it failed.

Comment: I meant to say I tried redirection codes to use in htaccess. Will edit my question. Thanks.